# How long will a peanut butter sandwich last?

Tags: butter, sandwich, peanut-butter

So, I made a peanut butter sandwich the other day but forgot about it and left it (wrapped in gladwrap) out in room temperature for 6 hours. (Brioche bun as the bread, peanut butter and butter) and I was wondering if it would be ok to eat as I ate it anyways.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Chode, was your sandwich just peanut butter, or was something else in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long do peanut butter sandwiches last at room temperature?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/55849/how-long-do-peanut-butter-sandwiches-last-at-room-temperature)

Comment: Hey @GdD thankyou for the welcoming, so sorry for my late reply. The sandwich had peanut butter and salted butter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, peanut butter has a fairly good shelf life. Putting it on bread doesn't change that.

Ordinary salted butter should also be alright for a day or two, as long as it wasn't in direct sunlight or high moisture or anything like that.

Most importantly, both butter and peanut butter will not spoil in a way that goes unnoticed. They will smell or feel wrong very obviously.

Disclaimer: This is not restaurant level hygiene advice, and probably contradicts public-health guidelines. It's certainly good enough for your own sandwiches though.